# Informix driver

Tags: vb.net, informix

We are querying an informix database. We have noticed that if we make the calls with the driver odbc informix-cli we have response times much slower than when we make calls using a jdbc driver.
This last driver, however, we can not use it from .net applications. Can you suggest some solutions to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Informix, you may be able to use the IBM DB2 driver if your Informix installation has DRDA enabled.  The DRDA (IBM Data Server .NET Provider) offers more features for .NET applications than SQLI (IBM Informix .NET Provider).    See IBM's site [Differences between .NET Providers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.cpi.doc/ids_cpi_010.htm) for a deeper explanation.